# How to make a directory structure from list

Tags: python, list, random, directory

I've been looking into this but im not having much luck.

The idea is that python should generate 10 separate 6 digit random codes,  these 6 digit codes can then be used as folder names.  this seems like such a simple task and i have been using the makedirs to attempt it but so far no luck,   can someone please give a quick example on how this would be done?

Comment: [what-have-you-tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 4):

Don't know why I did this for you. Feeling generous.

```
from random import randint
import os

nums = 10
digits = 6

for i in range(nums):
    value = "".join([str(randint(0,9)) for _ in range(digits)])
    os.mkdir(value)
```

Comment: you are more generous than you realise lol,  im only just starting out and this has taken me all day :D lol many thanks

Comment: That's okay. Hope you understand it. It uses a `list comprehension`, two `range` objects, and a `for` iteration. Look these up, they are important to know about.

Comment: my biggest problem with examples and what iv read is getting it to relate to what i need from the code,  i get it now :D  plus reading up on for loops again now with better understanding.  again many thanks ;)

Comment: @Joe you can drop the list comprehension, in favour of a generator expression: `''.join(str...)` . Works exactly the same way, except that it doesn't precompute the full list. Plus, it makes it slightly easier to read, and may even have a marginal performance benefit.

Comment: @lvc It would be worth testing, certainly, re the difference between constructing an iterator vs a list. I have to disagree about readability for a beginner, though. It looks a bit more magical, could confuse the difference between `( ... )` as an argument container, generator expression container, tuple container...

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from os import mkdir
>>> from random import randint
>>> files = [str(randint(0, 10**6)).zfill(6) for _ in range(10)]
>>> files
['541053', '822700', '114954', '900634', '245858', '060055', '538329', '070579', '965626', '164178']
>>> for f in files: os.mkdir(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is reasonably easy with the `random` and `os` modules.

```
import random
import os

def random_n_digit( n ):
    return random.randint( 10**(n-1), 10 ** n - 1 )

def create_dirs( digits = 6, numdirs = 10 ):
    for i in xrange(numdirs):
        os.mkdir(str(random_n_digit(digits)))

create_dirs()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint
from os import mkdir

total = 10

# create a generator
names = ('%06d' % randint(0,999999) for _ in xrange(total))
for name in names:
    mkdir(name)
```

Comment: I must say, I am genuinely puzzled about the `mkdir = os.mkdir` line. Why?

Comment: Efficiency. He was saving himself from having to type 3 characters by typing 8 extra characters.

Comment: Wow, you think thats why I did that? I was going for a performance efficient answer. If he were to generate many more directories you can make it faster by removing the dot notation access to the mkdir member: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Avoiding_dots...

Comment: the usual way to do that would be `from os import mkdir`, but it's a needless optimisation in this case.

Comment: Eh maybe not too much of a gain in this case. But its definitely not for the sake of saving the typing of characters lol

Comment: You may save a few nanoseconds in lookup by assigning os.mkdir to a local, but the cost of creating a directory on a spinning rust disk is milliseconds -- 5-6 orders of magnitude greater.

Comment: Yes, why not use the `from os import mkdir` syntax? Especially since you used it for `randint`.